# Horizontal centering which works in all browsers

Tags: html, css

Is there a non-javascript way to center the very first container div of a page which would work with IE, FF as well as chrome?

`margin:0 auto;` does not work in IE8 :(

Comment: It always worked for me on IE8. Strange. Anything more specific?

Comment: I have not declared any properties for "body". The frst div contains everything else and this is declared margin:0 auto. IE did not center it. Other people have also reported the same problem with IE :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should most certainly work in IE8, the reason why it doesn't work for you could be that your IE is in quirks mode, possibly due to a missing DocType.
Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:50%;margin:auto;border:1px solid black;">TEST</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. Doctype was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`margin:0 auto;` [works in IE8](http://dorward.me.uk/www/centre/#where-bugs-appear) if you have a Doctype that triggers [standards mode](http://gutfeldt.ch/matthias/articles/doctypeswitch.html).

If you don't have one, you should. If you really don't want one then [you can hack around it](http://dorward.me.uk/www/centre/#no-auto-margins).

Answer (score 1):

`margin: 0 auto;` works in all browsers (even as far as IE6).

You are either

- not specifying a `width` property so your container is actually centered it's just covering 100% of the width, or
- have messed up the selector, try a property like `color` or debug with [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)
- are triggering quirks mode because you are not specifying a doctype
- have a lot of errors in your markup; try [validating your markup](http://validator.w3.org/) and fixing bad markup — so browsers don't have to guess (and possibly interpret your markup differently)

Answer (score 0):

I found a not-so-good workaround for this

http://www.bluerobot.com/web/css/center1.html

If someone knows a better solution, please mention it here.

Answer (score 0):

It works in IE8 but you have to notice IE8 that its a good idea to visualize your webpage with the IE8 standard mode... :S by this tag in the header:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8"/>
```